# yum + skip broker or exclude rpms

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

during yum update on one of our rhel 7.6 server we get the following error

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libtirpc-devel-0.2.4-0.6.el7.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libtirpc = 0.2.4-0.6.el7
           Removing: libtirpc-0.2.4-0.6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.2)
               libtirpc = 0.2.4-0.6.el7
           Updated By: libtirpc-0.2.4-0.15.el7.x86_64 (uaans75-repo)
               libtirpc = 0.2.4-0.15.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

the are two solution for this problem

first solution is to exclude the problematic rpm  as

```
 yum update --exclude=libtirpc --exclude=rpcbind --exclude=nfs-utils
```

or to use the skip-broken

```
 yum update --skip-broken
```

about the first suggestion , I think we can install the non update rpm after yum update

so my question is

what is the preferred solution ? ( exclude rpm or to use skip broken ? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***--skip-broken*** will skip all unresolved dependencies.
Meanwhile ***--exclude*** will exclude a specific package from being updated.
The problem here is that you don't have the correct dependency for the package libtirpc-devel.

Try to find the correct repository.

But if you don't bother installing this package I suggest to use ***--exclude*** as long as you will be controlling what you are doing and avoiding packages conflict.